# Setting up snort

Tags: command-line, snort

I'm doing a project for a class, and I keep running into an issue. The professor and tutor are unable to help. I entered the following commands to install snort onto Ubuntu: (DAQ was already installed)

```bsh
sudo apt-get install libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libluajit-5.1-dev luajit
sudo apt-get install libdumbnet-dev
wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/snort-2.9.12.tar.gz
tar xvzf snort-2.9.12.tar.gz
cd snort-2.9.12
./configure --enable-sourcefire --disable-open-appid
make
sudo checkinstall
sudo dpkg -i snort_2.9.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/snort /usr/sbin/snort
sudo ldconfig -v
snort -V # used to test snort
cd -
```

I then downloaded the snort rules snapshot, and ran the following commands:

```
cd
cd Downloads
sudo mkdir -p /etc/snort
sudo tar -xvzf snortrules-snapshot-29110.tar.gz –C /etc/snort/
sudo touch /etc/snort/rules/white_list.rules
sudo touch /etc/snort/rules/black_list.rules
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/snort_dynmicrules
sudo mv /etc/snort/etc/* etc/snort
```

but when I enter the last command `sudo mv /etc/snort/etc/* etc/snort`, I get the following error message:

```
mv: target 'etc/snort' is not a directory
```

Comment: Did you mean `sudo mv /etc/snort/etc/* /etc/snort`? Your command line is missing the leading slash there…

Comment: And have you checked? It there a directory named `etc` in the current directory? Does it contain a directory named `snort`? If not, why would you expect the `mv` command to work?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what was wrong with installing Snort from [universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=snort) as simple as `sudo apt install snort`?

Comment: @N0rbert This repo has v2.9.7 even for Cosmic while OP tries to install v2.9.12. The differences are not trivial, see [the changelog](https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/changelog_2.9.12.txt).

Answer (score 1):

The last command is incorrect. You are getting the `mv: target 'etc/snort' is not a directory` error message because `etc/snort` is not a directory, but `/etc/snort` is a directory. The last command should be:

```
sudo mv /etc/snort/etc/* /etc/snort
```